# Fedora Xampp problems

Tags: xampp, fedora

I have just recently installed fedora on my new netbook and was looking into a way of running a web development server on it. I am easily able to get it installed and running however when I went to use it i found that I didnt  have sufficient rights to put content there. I have since tried to change the doccument root using sudo vi. Then when I connect to localhost using a browser it says that permission is dennied to the files. SO then I used the GUI to allow the "other" group to have full acess it works perfectly. Until I reboot in which case I can no longer log on with out getting the something has gone wrong screen. If someone has had the same problem or know how to solve it the help would be greatly apreciated